# Apache commons csv skip lines

Tags: java, csv

How to skip lines in input file with [apache commons csv](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/). In my file first few lines are <s>garbage</s> useful meta-information like date, etc. Can't find any options for this.

```
private void parse() throws Exception {
    Iterable<CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL
            .withQuote('"').withDelimiter(';').parse(new FileReader("example.csv"));
    for (CSVRecord csvRecord : records) {
        //do something            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `FileReader.readLine()` before starting the `for-loop`.

**Your example:**

```
private void parse() throws Exception {
  FileReader reader = new FileReader("example.csv");
  reader.readLine(); // Read the first/current line.

  Iterable <CSVRecord> records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withQuote('"').withDelimiter(';').parse(reader);
  for (CSVRecord csvRecord: records) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So simple. What if I don't know how many lines to skip and have to check the content of the line. I would "loose" the line read from stream

Comment: The direction of this answer is correct but this code will not compile because you should use `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));`

Comment: readLine ? What if a column contains CR LF ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in facility to skip an unknown number of lines.

If you want to skip only the first line (the header line), you can call `withSkipHeaderRecord()` while building the parser.

A more general solution would be to call `next()` on the iterator:

```
Iterable<CSVRecord> parser = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse(new FileReader("example.csv"));
Iterator<CSVRecord> iterator = parser.iterator();

for (int i = 0; i < amountToSkip; i++) {
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        iterator.next();
    }
}

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    CSVRecord record = iterator.next();
    System.out.println(record);
}
```

Comment: Setting the `withSkipHeaderRecord()` alone doesn't do the job. You have to instruct the parser about the first record being header by calling `withFirstRecordAsHeader()` first.

Answer (score 1):

So `CSVParser.iterator()` *should most definitely not* throw an exception on `iterator.hasNext()` as it makes it near impossible to recover during an error condition.

But where there is a will there is a way, and I present a *Terrible Idea that sorta works™*

```
    public void runOnFile(Path file) {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = fixHeaders(file);
            CSVParser parsed = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withFirstRecordAsHeader().parse(in);
            Map<String, Integer> headerMap = parsed.getHeaderMap();

            String line;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                try {
                    CSVRecord record = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(headerMap.keySet().toArray(new String[headerMap.keySet().size()]))
                            .parse(new StringReader(line)).getRecords().get(0);
                    // do something with your record
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("ignoring line:" + line);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: readLine ? What if a column contains CR LF ?

Comment: It's a terrible idea that sorta works. Adjust to your needs :)

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the header line using this

```
        Reader excelInput = new FileReader("example.csv");

        CSVFormat csvFormat = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withSkipHeaderRecord(true).withHeader("Arm1", "Arm2", "Arm3", "Arm4",
            "Arm5", "Arm6");

        CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(excelInput, csvFormat);
```

The key point is to set `withSkipHeaderRecord()` to `true` and also specify the headers that you want to skip inside `withHeader()`.

If you are aware of the line numbers you want to skip, you could do something like this:

```
for(CVSRecord csvRecord: CSVParser){
   if(csvRecord.getRecordNumber() == 1){
      continue;
  } 
}
```

where line 1 is what you want to skip.

Answer (score 0):

Check out CSVRecord.isConsistent() - which returns true if the record's size matches the header. I've had good success using this in conjunction with proper header setting on my CSVFormat.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the headers is advance, it's easy :

```
CSVFormat format;

String[] headers;
format = format.builder().setHeader(headers).build();
try(Reader reader = getReader()) {
  Iterator<CSVRecord> iter = format.parse(reader).iterator();
  //skip record
  if(iter.hasNext()) iter.next();
  //skip record
  if(iter.hasNext()) iter.next();

  while(iter.hasNext()) {
    CSVRecord record = iter.next();
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

If you don't know the headers you have to read twice (if possible) :

```
List<String> headers = null;
try(Reader reader = getReader() {
  Iterator<CSVRecord> iter = format.parse(reader).iterator();
  //skip record
  if(iter.hasNext()) iter.next();
  if(iter.hasNext()) headers = iter.next().toList();
}

if(headers == null) return;

//now read again
try(Reader reader = getReader() {
  format = format.builder().setHeader(headers.toArray(new String[0])).build();
  iter = format.parse(reader).iterator();
  if(iter.hasNext()) iter.next();
  if(iter.hasNext()) iter.next();
  while(iter.hasNext()) {
    CSVRecord record = iter.next();
    // do stuff
  }
}
```