# How to skip a few initial rows while parsing CSV using jackson-dataformat-csv?

Tags: java, csv, jackson

I have a CSV of the following format:

```
New CSV file

header_1,header_2,header_3,header_4
value_1,value_2,value_3,value_4
value_1,value_2,value_3,value_4
value_1,value_2,value_3,value_4
```

I have the following code for parsing this CSV:

```
    CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
    CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withSkipFirstDataRow(true);
    List<CsvModel> rows = new LinkedList<>();
    MappingIterator<CsvModel> iterator = csvMapper
            .readerFor(CsvModel.class).with(schema)
            .readValues(filePath.toFile());
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        CsvModel csvElement = iterator.next();
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(csvElement.getValue1())) {
            // skip lines not having the value
            continue;
        }
        rows.add(csvElement);
    }
```

However, I am getting the following exception while parsing the above mentioned CSV-format file:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.RuntimeJsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.adapters.CsvParsing: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('')
 at [Source: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.impl.UTF8Reader@2cb566f1; line: 2, column: 1]
```

This is because the second line is empty. I need to skip the first two lines, how do I tell jackson to skip the first two lines of the file?

**Edit 1:**
Here is the CsvModel file:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class CsvModel {
    public static final String IdField = "Id";
    public static final String NameField = "Name";
    public static final String GuidField = "Guid";
    public static final String SubscriptionNameField = "Subscription Name";
    public static final String DateField = "Date";
    public static final String CostField = "Cost";

    @JsonProperty(IdField)
    private String Id;
    @JsonProperty(NameField)
    private String Name;
    @JsonProperty(GuidField)
    private String Guid;
    @JsonProperty(SubscriptionNameField)
    private String SubscriptionName;
    @JsonProperty(DateField)
    private String Date;
    private Long epochDate;
    @JsonProperty(CostField)
    private Double Cost;

    public String getId() {
        return this.Id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }

    public String getGuid() {
        return this.Guid;
    }

    public void setGuid(String guid) {
        this.Guid = guid;
    }

    public String getSubscriptionName() {
        return this.SubscriptionName;
    }

    public void setSubscriptionName(String subscriptionName) {
        this.SubscriptionName = subscriptionName;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return this.Date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.Date = date;
    }

    public Long getEpochDate() {
        return this.epochDate;
    }

    public void setEpochDate(Long epochDate) {
        this.epochDate = epochDate;
    }

    public Double getCost() {
        return this.Cost;
    }

    public void setCost(Double cost) {
        this.Cost = cost;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To skip empty lines you can use SKIP_EMPTY_LINES feature:

```
CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper().enable(CsvParser.Feature.SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

CsvSchema schema = csvMapper.emptySchema().withSkipFirstDataRow(true);
MappingIterator<Account> dataIterator = csvMapper.readerFor(CsvModel.class).with(schema)
    .readValues(file);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can skip the first two rows by advancing the iterator twice before processing, e.g.:

```
for(int i=0 ; i<2 ; i++){
    if(iterator.hasNext()){
        iterator.next();
    }
}

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
...
```

This will make sure no `Exception` gets thrown if let's say the file has less than 2 records.

**Update**

Editing the answer based on question edits:

The reason why it throws `RuntimeJsonMappingException` is because it is interpreting one line of vsc file as a string and is trying to bind `String` to `CsvModel` object. You need to specify a (non empty) `schema` with `csvMapper` mapper which acts as `metadata` while deserializing one line, e.g.:

```
CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema.builder()
        .setColumnSeparator(',')
        .addColumn("Id")
        .addColumn("name")
        ....
```

You can have a look at [this](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper) example.

Comment: Forgot to mention I have tried this and this fails with the same exception I have mentioned above: `no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('')` on the line `iterator.next();`

Comment: Can you share the structure of `CsvModel`?

Comment: Have shared the relevant piece of code. I had to edit some parts which aren't relevant here.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: This would mean I have to map my columns in the schema right? I am anyway doing it in the model (the POJO), isn't that kind of duplication?

Comment: You are defining an empty schema i.e. `CsvSchema schema = CsvSchema.emptySchema().withSkipFirstDataRow(true);` and not specifying bean class in it. Have a look at the seond example in the link, e.g.:  `mapper.schemaFor(CsvModel.class);`

Comment: It is now trying to deserialize the header value and failing because one of the headers is not serializable to a Double value. Failing with the exception `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.RuntimeJsonMappingException: Can not deserialize value of type java.lang.Double from String "Guid": not a valid Double value
 at [Source: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.impl.UTF8Reader@1dbabc13; line: 3, column: 75] (through reference chain: com.adapters.CsvParsing["Cost"])` which means it is trying to parse the headers, which now I have no way to specify it is a header and not to parse it.

Comment: Why is it tryinh to deserialise the header value? Are you not skipping the first two rows as I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: I am skipping the first three rows (since the header is the third row), but since the third row is the header value, it is skipping but still trying to map to the POJO before skipping, and hence failing with the above mentioned exception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142499/discussion-between-darshan-mehta-and-jobin).

Comment: It should not be deserialising the third row, can you copy my for loop with i < 3 before deserialization code?

Answer (score 0):

A better answer will be to consume the first few lines using `BufferedReader.readLine()`.

Refer to this [Apache commons csv skip lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33972243/apache-commons-csv-skip-lines).

Sample code:

```
try (final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {
  // consume the first few lines here
  reader.readLine();
  reader.readLine();

  final MappingIterator<MyClass> readValues =
    new CsvMapper()
         .readerFor(MyClass.class)
         .with(emptySchema()
                .withHeader()
                .withNullValue(""))
         .readValues(reader);

  final List<MyClass> records = readValues.readAll();
} catch (Exception e) {
  log.warn("Failed to read detail section of transactionItem file.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still looking for a solution:

```
    File tempFile = new File(tempLocation + csvFile.getName()); // tempLocation as per your choice
    List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(csvFile, encoding); // apache.commons - FileUtils
    if(!importingFile.exists())
        importingFile.createNewFile();

    int lineNum = 0;
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(importingFile, "UTF-8");
    for(String line : lines){

        if(lineNum == 0){ continue; } // Skip the first line, if required

        /**
         * Here removes all special characters other than numbers and alphabets.
         * Because in my case there was some unknown characters in the file.
         */
        String filtered = line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
        if( null == filtered || "".equals(filtered.trim()))){
            continue;
        }
        printWriter.println(line);
        lineNum++;
    }
    if(printWriter != null) printWriter.close();

    CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper(); //  jackson.dataformat - CsvMapper
    mapper.enable(CsvParser.Feature.SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

    CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(CsvModel.class).withHeader()
            .withColumnSeparator(';')
            .withColumnReordering(true);
    ObjectReader reader = mapper.readerFor(CsvModel.class).with(schema);

    List list = reader.readValues(new FileInputStream(tempFile)).readAll();
```